# Block some mouse event of QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, pyside, qgraphicsview

I have my own subclass of `QGraphicsScene` lied behind `QGrapnhicsView` (I did not override it). My scene handles some mouse events (double and single click). But in the same time I want my view will be scrollable by cursor (`QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag`). How could I block mouse event on view layer if it already caused scrolling, to not to bubble to the scene?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `mouseMoveEvent` function from [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsview.html#mouseMoveEvent) and accept the event.

```
protected:
virtual void QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QPoint mouseLocation = event->pos();
    // Do stuff
    event->accept();
}
```

Accepting the mouse event [prevents a parent class from handling that event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qevent.html#accept).

This would prevent mouse move events from being propagated. Depending on what you want to do, you could also reimplement the `mouseDoubleClickEvent`, `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleasEvent`, or `wheelEvent` functions. All of their function definitions are in the [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsview.html#mouseMoveEvent) documentation.

Comment: It is not working in case of PySide. If I overrides any mouse-related methods and do not call parent's method explicitly scrolling functionality of QGraphicsView is not working. If I calling it explicitly and call `accept` method of event it is doing nothing - still propagated to scene.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Qt documentation, you'll need to actually subclass the `QGraphicsView` and reimplement the `mouseMoveEvent()` method for your new subclass.

**Reference:** http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#dragMode-prop